# C comparing char does not work

Tags: c, struct, char, compare, do-while

we're supposed to code an householdbook, where we got a struct like this

```
typedef struct{
   struct Entry *before;
   char date[8];
   char type;
   float price;
   char comment[250];
   struct Entry *following;
} Entry;
```

The first function you should call is

```
addEntry()
```

There you can add entries to the householdbook. When you put in the type, you say if its income or expense. My problem there is, that the if clause isn't comparing correctly, because it asks for new inout all the time.

```
do {
       printf("Income or Expense?: ");
       scanf(" %c", &(ptr->type));
       printf("%c\n", ptr->type);
       if(ptr->type == 'i')
              ptr->type = "I";
       if(ptr->type == 'e')
              ptr->type = "E";
} while(ptr->type != 'I' || ptr->type != 'E');
```

When I hit a letter on my keyboard, the `printf`function outputs the right one, but it never exits this `do{} while()`loop somehow also if i put a capital `'E'` or `'I'` in. And it never makes a small `'e'` or `'i'` to a captial one.

Comment: Please, before doing anything else with this code, replace `(*ptr).type` with `ptr->type` (for all the members, of course) throughout. Also, the logic sounds strange ("while (type is not 1) OR (type is not 2)" sounds like it's always true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(*ptr).type != 'I' || (*ptr).type != 'E'
```

is always true. Did you mean :

```
(*ptr).type != 'I' && (*ptr).type != 'E'
```

Comment: gosh, you were quick, didn't have time to finish writing ^^

Comment: Yeah :D Thanks! That was what was wrong. And I sit here like 30 Minutes and changed and changed the code but it didn't worked :D